# Sorting a dictionary according to values in sub dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows

```
{"SPORTS": {"data": [["Bball", "10", 3]], "columns": ["SPORT", "MATCHES", "WINS"]}, "GRAMMY": {"data": [["Billy Joel", "Rock", 1], ["Elton John", "FUnk", 2]], "columns": ["ARTIST", "GENRE", "ID"]}, "SONGS": {"data": [], "columns": ["NAME", "ARTIST", "SONG_ID"]}}
```

I want to sort this dictionary by the size of the "data" list . In other words  the above I want sorted as

```
{"GRAMMY": {"data": [["Billy Joel", "Rock", 1], ["Elton John", "FUnk", 2]], "columns": ["ARTIST", "GENRE", "ID"]},"SPORTS": {"data": [["Bball", "10", 3]], "columns": ["SPORT", "MATCHES", "WINS"]}, "SONGS": {"data": [], "columns": ["NAME", "ARTIST", "SONG_ID"]}
}
```

where Grammy Table has 2 rows, Sports Table has one row and SONGS has none

Comment: This is just for printing it out, right? Dictionaries cannot stay sorted.

Comment: I want to turn it into a JSON string later which I want to loop in the front end

Comment: JSON objects are also not ordered.

Comment: Ok then my problem is to loop through this dictionary that I access elements in the order I mentioned

Comment: You want a list. And there are json arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind creating a new dictionary, you can sort a list of key value pairs and then add those to an OrderedDict (in the collections library) which remembers the insertion order.  Then that can be dumped as a JSON object in the order you want.

```
d = {"SPORTS": {"data": [["Bball", "10", 3]], "columns": ["SPORT", "MATCHES", "WINS"]}, "GRAMMY": {"data": [["Billy Joel", "Rock", 1], ["Elton John", "FUnk", 2]], "columns": ["ARTIST", "GENRE", "ID"]}, "SONGS": {"data": [], "columns": ["NAME", "ARTIST", "SONG_ID"]}}
newd = OrderedDict(sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]['data']), reverse=True))
# change iteritems to items if python 3
# newd holds the sorted dictionaries
```

If you're alright with a JSON list instead of an object then just remove the OrderedDict constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to do this.

> Ordered dictionaries are just like regular dictionaries but they remember the order that items were inserted. When iterating over an ordered dictionary, the items are returned in the order their keys were first added.

So the solution is to transform the original dict into a list of key-value pairs, order it and then construct an `OrderedDict` from the resulting list.

```
>>> d = {"SPORTS": {"data": [["Bball", "10", 3]], "columns": ["SPORT", "MATCHES", "WINS"]}, "GRAMMY": {"data": [["Billy Joel", "Rock", 1], ["Elton John", "FUnk", 2]], "columns": ["ARTIST", "GENRE", "ID"]}, "SONGS": {"data": [], "columns": ["NAME", "ARTIST", "SONG_ID"]}}
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k, v): len(v["data"]), reverse=True))OrderedDict([('GRAMMY', {'data': [['Billy Joel', 'Rock', 1], ['Elton John', 'FUnk', 2]], 'columns': ['ARTIST', 'GENRE', 'ID']}), ('SPORTS', {'data': [['Bball', '10', 3]], 'columns': ['SPORT', 'MATCHES', 'WINS']}), ('SONGS', {'data': [], 'columns': ['NAME', 'ARTIST', 'SONG_ID']})])
OrderedDict([('GRAMMY', {'data': [['Billy Joel', 'Rock', 1], ['Elton John', 'FUnk', 2]], 'columns': ['ARTIST', 'GENRE', 'ID']}), ('SPORTS', {'data': [['Bball', '10', 3]], 'columns': ['SPORT', 'MATCHES', 'WINS']}), ('SONGS', {'data': [], 'columns': ['NAME', 'ARTIST', 'SONG_ID']})])
```